# How to access Linux files in WSL (windows 10 fall creators update)?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-10-v1709

It seems the old way for `Creators Update`:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\lxss
```

is not working (there is no lxss folder)

How can I access Linux files in `Fall Creators Update`?

Answer (score 0):

Oops, in fact, it is not recommended edit Linux files by Windows app
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/